# How to use interface to type function argument in Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to implement a React component that contains a list of options and shows their `id` and `name`. I want this component to be reusable so I define an interface `Option` to ensure the required fields are always provided.

And here comes the issue: if I pass any type with more fields than those 2 `{ id, name, /* anything */}`, Flow complains. Is it not possible to use interfaces in Flow like this?

Here's the minimal relevant code:

```js
interface Option {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

const List = (options: Option[]) => {
  options.forEach(o => null)
}

type ImplementsOption = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  description: string
}

const plans: ImplementsOption[] = []

List(plans)
```

Error:

> Cannot call `List` with `plans` bound to `options` because property `description` is missing in `Option` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChllgATALmQGcwpQBzAGmORDgFsIrb6QHCAX0KEEuWsgAywCQF5kACmyYcIalQxZcAbQC6ASmSyAfAVbKtagHQxsUAKKIAFkqOmQAVwA2X-UJFgAJ7oKACSHOheEFzg1JqqRmYk5Dx0jCwk7FypfMysZBDUCPQquDmM-qLiYMiRcGpU4ZHRELHxOrqJeiLStAp1an6EAPTDyADCcLQVvWAK-V716milIHr6Q6MTi9TUhaI71BPYEVEAHu14wKctsSuWSaSUNGn8rFncL7mVYmo1YjcLqtluMTs0gZY9F1dD0ZHMAeDLtR9EA) but exists in `ImplementsOption` [2] in array element.

Trying with casting:

```js
List((plans: Option[]))
```

And also with classes:

```js
class ComplexOption implements Option {
  id: string
  name: string
}

const complexOptions: ComplexOption[] = []

List(complexOptions)
```

Nothing seems to work!

There is a [playground](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChllgATALmQGcwpQBzAGmORDgFsIrb6QHCAX0KEEuWsgAywCQF5kACmyYcIalQxZcAbQC6ASmSyAfAVbKtagHQxsUAKKIAFkqOmQAVwA2X-UJFgAJ7oKACSHOheEFzg1JqqRmYk5Dx0jCwk7FypfMysZBDUCPQquDmM-qLiYMiRcGpU4ZHRELHxOrqJeiLStAp1an6EAPTDyADCcLQVvWAK-V716milIHr6Q6MTi9TUhaI71BPYEVEAHu14wKctsSuWSaSUNGn8rFncL7mVYmo1YjcLqtluMTs0gZY9F1dD0ZHMAeDLtR9EA) with all these snippets already.

Comment: `{}` is not type of `ImplementsOption` as it miss `id`, `name` & `description`, why you expect it to be ok?

Comment: Right, I'll fix the snippet. That's not the issue in this particular case however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine we had a list of `ImplementsOption`: `[{ id: 'id', name: 'name', description: 'description' }, ...]`. Now we pass it into the `List` function, which has the signature `Option[] => void`. This is totally valid from the point of view of `List` since `ImplementOption` is a supertype of `Option`. However, there is no guarantee in the `List` function that it won't modify the list that is passed in. Thus, the function could add an element of type `Option` to the list, which would be valid for a `Option[]` but invalid for a `ImplementsOption[]`.

To fix this, you can type `plans` as a `$ReadOnlyArray<Option>`, which tells Flow that the `List` function will not modify the elements ([try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChllgATALmQGcwpQBzAGmORDgFsIrb6QHCAX0KEEuWsgAywCQF5kACmyYcIalQAkAJQhwyqEABsAngEEoUOMYA8GLLgB8ASmSyHBVsvtqAdDGxQAKKIABZKru4gAK6Ghk5CImDG6CgAkhzohhBc4NR2qq4eJOQ8dIwsJOxcpXzMrGQQ1Aj0Krg1jAmi4mDImXBqVOmZ2RC5+bgA2gC6hdMi0rQKfWpOQA)).

Reference issues [#4425](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4425), [#4483](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4483), or [#5206](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5206) for more information.

Comment: Grand! Thanks a lot!